# Is there a simple way to transform an array based on a dimension table?

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

I have two tables:

- One with a column with is an array of identifiers.
- Another which is a dimension table of that map these identifiers to another value

I'm looking to transform the column of the first table using the dimension table.

Example:

Table 1:

`Column A  | Column B`

`'Bob'      |  ['a', 'b', 'c']`

`'Terry'      |  ['a']`

Dimension Table:

`Column C  | Column D`

`'a'      |  1`

`'b'      |  2`

`'c'      |  3`

---

Expected Output:

`Column A  | Column B`

`'Bob'      |  [1,2,3]`

`'Terry'      |  [1]`

Is there a way to do this (preferably in Presto) without exploding and re-aggregating the array column ?

Answer (score 1):

i guess you would be able to do this without exploding and re-aggregation by using [transform_keys](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html), not sure this is easier though.

```
SELECT map_keys(transform_keys(MAP(ARRAY['a','c'], ARRAY[null,null]),
                      (k, v) -> MAP(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ARRAY[1,2,3,4])[k]));
```

I guess it requires that the dimension table is not "too big".